# How to merge two textures

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es

I am trying to get a texture by binding two textures.But only one texture is displaying in the screen.
The code bellow is how I load the texture..

```
- (void)loadTexture:(NSString *)name intoLocation:(GLuint)location {

CGImageRef textureImage = [UIImage imageNamed:name].CGImage;
if (textureImage == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to load texture image");
    return;
}

NSInteger texWidth = CGImageGetWidth(textureImage);
NSInteger texHeight = CGImageGetHeight(textureImage);

GLubyte *textureData = (GLubyte *)malloc(texWidth * texHeight * 4);

CGContextRef textureContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(textureData,
                                                    texWidth, texHeight,
                                                    8, texWidth * 4,
                                                    CGImageGetColorSpace(textureImage),
                                                    kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
CGContextDrawImage(textureContext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, (float)texWidth, (float)texHeight), textureImage);
CGContextRelease(textureContext);
glActiveTexture(location);
glGenTextures(3, &location);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,2);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texWidth, texHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);

free(textureData);

glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);}
```

And here the method where I call the texture load :

```
- (BOOL)createFramebuffer {
CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer;

eaglLayer.opaque = YES;
eaglLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking, kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8,
                                kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat, nil];

context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1];

if (!context || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context]) {
    [self release];

}
    [self setupView];
 glGenTextures(0, &textures[3]);

[self loadTexture:@"image1.png" intoLocation:textures[1]];
[self loadTexture:@"image2.png" intoLocation:textures[0]];




glGenFramebuffersOES(2, &viewFramebuffer);
glGenRenderbuffersOES(2, &viewRenderbuffer);

glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);

[context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer];
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);

glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);

if (USE_DEPTH_BUFFER) {
    glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorageOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES, backingWidth, backingHeight);
    glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);
}

if(glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES) {
    NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES));
    return NO;
}

return YES;
```

}

I hope now is more clear about what I need.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do. "Merging two textures" without further context can mean anything and nothing at all. Also explain what exactly you have tried so far.

Comment: I suspect that when you say "merge" what you really mean is "blend". In which case, you do not actually get a texture, but combine the results of drawing using one texture with previous results (e.g. the other texture) to produce a new pixel. In many cases (e.g. alpha blending) this is an order-dependent operation. Whatever the case, without seeing any sort of code or better description there is no way to answer this.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for updating your question with actual code. Now, one thing strikes me as unusual in your code, and it has to do with your variable called `location`.

```
glActiveTexture (location);
glGenTextures   (3, &location);
glBindTexture   (GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2);
glTexImage2D    (GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texWidth, texHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);
```

`glActiveTexture (...)` sets the texture unit which all calls that modify TMU (Texture Mapping Unit) state refer to. In desktop OpenGL it can have any value within the range: `GL_TEXTURE0` to `GL_TEXTURE0 + 79`. OpenGL ES 2.0 guarantees 2 TMUs and iOS (which has always run on PowerVR SGX hardware gives you 8).

The problem I have is that immediately after setting the active texture unit using the variable `location`, you try to generate 3 texture names (handles) and store them in an array of `GLuint` named `location`.

`location` cannot be both an array of texture names and the TMU you want to bind. What is more, immediately after `glGenTextures (...)` you bind a texture named `2`, which makes very little sense. I would expect to see the next call to `glBindTexture (...)` following `glGenTextures (...)` to reference something from within the array: `location []`.

Making things worse, before calling `[self loadTexture:@"image1.png" intoLocation:textures[1]]`, you have a line of code: `glGenTextures(0, &textures[3]);` which tells OpenGL to generate 0 texture names and store them in an array of `GLuint` beginning at the address: `&textures [3]`.

There are just too many things wrong with your code to understand what you are actually trying to do. I think you may need to brush up on multi-texturing and texturing in general.